# how to obtain class name from column number after using multilabel_binarizer?

Tags: multilabel-classification

This is the code i wrote. After executution y contains 100 columns representing classes where values are 1 where that data point is in that class.

```
multilabel_binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()
multilabel_binarizer.fit(meta['Tags'])

# transform target variable
y = multilabel_binarizer.transform(meta['Tags'])
```

I want to obtain an array representing the class names represented by each column.I know inverse transform is used for this purpose but i am not able to figure out the syntax. If there is any other method please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function-

```
Classes= multilabel_binarizer.classes_
```